# Wolverine single lever shower faucet

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have a significant loss of pressure coming out of the shower head, I have checked the shower head for obstructions and it is clear. none of the other faucets in the house have this problem. Any ideas what it could be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. I'd suggest you [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how we operate. Is this drop in pressure recent? Is it a new shower head?

Comment: Has it always been this way or did it just happen? This might be normal. Modern shower heads have a flow restrictor to conserve water.

Comment: Did you try flushing out the pipe with the shower head moved?

Comment: Yes it's recent, like from one day to the next, and it's the same shower head that has been on for four or five years, I did not try flushing the pipe but I will, today

Comment: Sometimes scale , rust plugs the flow restrictor in the head or the valve, flow test will cut the problem in half. +